Set background image in all slides (Quarto - revealjs)
I work with Quarto (via RStudio) and I work on a revealjs presentation. I would like to apply the same background image (from a .png file in the same directory as the qmd) to all slides (without having to specify it on each slide header).
The closest question on Stack Overflow is [this one][1]. The code provided in the answer works. But when I change this line :
background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/8tcxHWh.jpeg");

to this :
background-image: "Background.png";

i.e., trying to point to a local file in the same directory as scss and qmd, it has no effect (no background image).
Does someone knows the answer to this ?

did you try the answer?

Could you please share some reproducible code?

I apologize for not being so clear in the first place. I edited the question to make it clearer, based on the example code provided in the question you also mentioned, @Julian.

My previous solution was not so perfect so I found another one. I hope it can help someone some day.
First, I created (or converted) my image into Inkscape and exported it to svg. I used Inkscape as it creates a nicely formatted svg when oppened with a text editor.
After exporting, I opened the image with a text editor and I changed all the "width" and "height" parameters to % instead of px (or whatever finite distance unit you might have). For my image, the svg looked like this :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   width="100%"
   height="100%"
   viewBox="0 0 338.66666 190.5"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg1"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs
     id="defs1" />
  <g
     id="layer1">
    <rect
       style="fill:#5ba500;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:0.355287"
       id="rect1"
       width="100%"
       height="7.3%"
       x="0%"
       y="92.9%" />
    <rect
       style="fill:#00716d;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:0.287288"
       id="rect1-7"
       width="100%"
       height="4.7%"
       x="0%"
       y="95.5%" />
  </g>
</svg>

This allows the background to be automatically rescaled to some extent (and especially, it fits the screen when in full screen mode).

I found a quite simple solution: just include it in YAML without using scss :
---
title: "Title"
format:
  revealjs:
    background-image: Background.png
---

IMPORTANT: it does not work on slides where the background is specified individually, so make sure to remove {background-image="image.jpg"} from second level headings.
